# How to read this particular data from a comma seperated csv file

Tags: java, csv

I will be getting the following csv file from third party

From this CSV File i want to extract the names from the below

(VEDL,RELIANCE,TATAMOTORS,NTPC,MARUTI)

```
,Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,PREV.CLOSE,%CHANGE
,VEDL,EQ,        85.00,        81.05,4.87
,RELIANCE,EQ,      1051.60,      1025.75,2.52
,TATAMOTORS,EQ,       360.20,       353.35,1.94
,NTPC,EQ,       141.60,       139.55,1.47
,MARUTI,EQ,      4272.40,      4214.75,1.37
```

**This is my program** which i got as reference .

```
package com.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedReader;
import java.io.PipedWriter;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String startToken = ",Nifty 50 Gainers";
        final String endToken = "50 Losers";
        final PipedWriter pipedWriter = new PipedWriter();
        PipedReader pipedReaderTmp = null;
        try {
            pipedReaderTmp = new PipedReader(pipedWriter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        final PipedReader pipedReader = pipedReaderTmp;
        // Consumer
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(pipedReader);
                    while (true) {
                        String[] line = csvReader.readNext(); // blocks until the next line is available
                        if (line == null)
                            break; // end of stream has been reached
                        if (line != null && line.length > 3) {
                            String indices_name = line[1];
                            if (indices_name != null) {

                                System.out.println(indices_name);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        // Producer
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            "C:\\Users\\ravikiranv\\Downloads\\MA050116.csv"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (startToken.equals(line))
                            break;
                    }
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.contains((endToken))) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            pipedWriter.write(line + '\n');
                        }
                    }
                    pipedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

But when i ran the program i am not getting anything in the pipedWriter

**The whole csv file looks this way**

```
,11-Jan-2016
The Nifty witnessed an intraday movement of about 110.75 points.The closing index was 0.49 % down as compared to the previous closing index.

, Traded Value (Rs. In Crores), 16359.76
, Traded Quantity (in Lakhs), 10682.44
, Number of Trades, 7547729
, Total Market Capitalisation (Rs. Crores), 9491205.95

,INDEX,PREVIOUS CLOSE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,GAIN/LOSS
,Nifty 50,      7601.35,      7527.45,      7605.10,      7494.35,      7563.85,-37.5
,Nifty IT,     10989.55,     10898.80,     10917.45,     10797.70,     10823.90,-165.65
,Nifty Next 50,     19598.75,     19483.55,     19530.85,     19275.80,     19379.80,-218.95
,Nifty Bank,     16142.65,     15979.05,     16156.80,     15840.60,     16016.25,-126.4

,ADVANCES,578
,DECLINES,994
,UNCHANGED,61

,Total securities that have hit their price bands today,152

,TOP 25 Securities Today :
,SYMBOL,SERIES,PREV. CLOSE,CLOSE PRICE,%VAR, VALUE(Rs Crs)
,RELIANCE,EQ,      1025.75,      1051.60,2.52,695.04
,AXISBANK,EQ,       413.70,       417.20,0.85,431.92
,SBIN,EQ,       208.95,       204.30,-2.23,394.82

,Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,PREV.CLOSE,%CHANGE
,VEDL,EQ,        85.00,        81.05,4.87
,RELIANCE,EQ,      1051.60,      1025.75,2.52
,TATAMOTORS,EQ,       360.20,       353.35,1.94
,NTPC,EQ,       141.60,       139.55,1.47
,MARUTI,EQ,      4272.40,      4214.75,1.37

,Top Five Nifty 50 Losers:
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,PREV.CLOSE,%CHANGE
,WIPRO,EQ,       537.45,       555.80,-3.3
,ADANIPORTS,EQ,       234.05,       241.40,-3.04
,M&M,EQ,      1162.60,      1198.00,-2.95
,TECHM,EQ,       507.30,       522.15,-2.84
,BHEL,EQ,       149.45,       153.60,-2.7

,Securities Price Volume Data in Normal market
,SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE PRICE,TRADED VALUE ,TRADED QUANTITY
,20MICRONS,EQ,        36.55,                  4494342.20,123972
,3IINFOTECH,EQ,         5.65,                 34819990.20,6217017
,3MINDIA,EQ,     10653.95,                  3626784.60,341
,8KMILES,EQ,      2356.70,                259881198.20,109041
,A2ZINFRA,EQ,        26.65,                  3515954.10,131509
,AARTIDRUGS,EQ,       560.00,                 15268435.55,27246
,AARTIIND,EQ,       508.80,                  8941675.40,17568
,AARVEEDEN,EQ,        63.75,                   174019.55,2769
```

Could you please let me know how to parse those five symbols and their data after the text

Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:

Comment: If this isn't homework, consider using a library e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: I am already using CSVReader

Comment: @BrandonLing sorry i didn't understand your question ..

Comment: i was asking if your start token and end token is correct, cause it does a .equals and not a .contains, and your start token isn't exactly the same as the  "Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:". this is just a quick glance though

Comment: actually start token should be ",Top Five Nifty 50 Gainers:" because it does a readline, and your end token should be ",Top Five Nifty 50 Losers:", assuming that the rest of your program is correct this should work. though this does does seem like you should be using a more simple library than writing two threads

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working absolutely fine .....